# Can't add Emacs tag to question

Tags: support, tags

I added the (existing) tag [emacs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs) to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/174049/73837), but when I save the edit, the tag is automatically removed from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Code Review, all question must have a language tag. For Emacs code, the language would be [elisp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elisp).

The [emacs] tag is retired, since it is a synonym of [elisp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elisp).

Comment: Ok, I've seen now that it redirects to `elisp`, I got confused because it is still an option for *tags* when adding a question (8 times used), I suppose for historical reasons.